# How strong is hash(x+y) if y is known?

Tags: security, hash

If you have two binary blobs, `x` and `y`. And you hash them together, let's say using `SHA-512`. And an intruder knows `y`, how much easier does it make reversing the hash?

Is there a guideline as to how big `y` and can be in comparison to `x` before it becomes a concern? Does it matter at all?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using a cryptographically strong hash (like SHA-512, or the new SHA3, but not a broken hash like MD4), then the difficulty of breaking `hash(x || y)` (where `||` denotes concatenation) is at least as hard as breaking `hash(x)` when `y` is known. There are many cases where adding a known `y` is useful:

- using a random `y` as a salt so hashing the same two `x`s produces different results
- adding a long padding string to slow down hash computations to hinder bruteforce (this can also be achieved by iterating the hash several times)
- as a nonce to create one-time shared keys

The security of these schemes depends on the above difficulty of breaking `hash(x || y)`.

Comment: The attacker is not supposed to know the salt, neither how many iterations it has been hashed with. This should only be known to the qualified users. Otherwise they are useless. If, however, the attacker is not aware of the extra data, there is an increased security.

Comment: But, if the attacker finds out the salt, at least he cannot use a rainbow table (precomputed hashes) to break the password. That's the whole point. Even if the attacker has the salt and the hash, the security is higher because precomputation cannot help.

Comment: You could just as well argue that "the attacker is not supposed to know the password" and store your passwords in plaintext in a "secure" database. After all, the hashes are "useless" if they are never revealed! But, everyone will tell you that storing passwords in plaintext is absolutely a bad idea. Security is all about layers of defense; just because the attackers *shouldn't* know the salt doesn't mean they *won't*.

Answer (score 1):

No stronger than `hash(x)` is in itself. The strength depends on which hashing algorithm you use, i.e if the intruder knows how you combined the two values, and he knows `y`, the strength is no better than if you'd just left `y` out.

Comment: I disagree that the security is no better than leaving `y` out. See my answer for cases in which adding a known `y` is better than leaving one out.